# How to use sqlmap when the injectable parameter is not a regular parameter?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I have a target website, which parameter is not a regular parameter, which looks like:

```
POST /some_url

'info={"actual_parameter1": "abc", "actual_parameter2": "def"}'
```

`info` is not the actual_parameter, but the `actual_parameter1` and `actual_parameter2` are.

How can I use sqlmap in this case?

Comment: I think you can add a star (*) to specify a custom injection point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLMap: Testing implicit parameter URL](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82083/sqlmap-testing-implicit-parameter-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the comments of this question, there are 2 ways to do it:

1. use `-p` parameter, e.g. `sqlmap -u test.com -p "a;b" --param-del=';'`
2. use `*` symbol, in any where, e.g. in cookie, in header, in url, ... sqlmap is clever enough to know this special symbol.